# Add transition effect to <td> <span> when updating text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a transition effect to a span within a td. I have some truncated text that updates to the full text when a user clicks on it. Currently it just jumps between sizes. What I'd like is a simple growing/scaling effect. Here is a simple [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ep96uhz0/2/).

html

```
<html>

<body>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    Header
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">
      <span class="ease truncated truncated-collapsed" data-truncated="Truncated Text...." data-fulltext="This is the full text content">
        Truncated Text....
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
    function onToggleTruncated(event) {
        let $elem = $(event.target)
        if ($elem.hasClass('truncated-collapsed')) {
            $elem.text($elem.data('fulltext'))
        } else {
            $elem.text($elem.data('truncated'))
        }
        $elem.toggleClass('truncated-collapsed')
    }

    $('.truncated').click(onToggleTruncated)
```

css

```
.ease {
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a width to transition it

```js
function onToggleTruncated(event) {
  let $elem = $(event.target)
  if ($elem.hasClass('truncated-collapsed')) {
    $elem.text($elem.data('fulltext'))
  } else {
    $elem.text($elem.data('truncated'))
  }
  $elem.toggleClass('truncated-collapsed')
}

$('.truncated').click(onToggleTruncated)
```

```css
.truncated {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncated-collapsed {
  width: 50px;
}

.ease {
  display: block;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        Header
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">
          <span class="ease truncated truncated-collapsed" data-truncated="Truncated Text" data-fulltext="This is the full text content">
        Truncated Text
      </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to accomplish this without setting an explicit width? Ie allow the table to natively size the <td>, but still animate the transition?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more instant reveal result just using opacity with your ease css transition you could use this...

Here is a fiddle here too https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/sjnp9g84/1/

See comments in script...

```js
// our truncate toggle function
function toggleTruncate() {

  // set this constant for time out usage
  const $this = $(this); 
  
  // if current trunc has show trunc
  if ($(this).hasClass('show-truncated')) {
  
    // remove this class to reset opacity back to 0
    $(this).removeClass('show-truncated');
    
    // very small time out to allow dom to render opacity to 0
    setTimeout(function() {
    
      // change text to full text then add show full text class to reveal with css transition
        $this.html($this.data('fulltext')).addClass('show-fulltext'); 
      
        }, 10 ); // 10 milisencond delay

  // else if current trunc has show full text
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('show-fulltext')) {
  
    // remove this class to reset opacity back to 0
    $(this).removeClass('show-fulltext');
    
    // very small time out to allow dom to render opacity to 0
    setTimeout(function() {
    
      // change text to trunc text then add show trunc class to reveal with css transition
        $this.html($this.data('truncated')).addClass('show-truncated'); 
      
        }, 10 ); // 10 milisencond delay
    
  }
  
}

// changed to on click with doc for all .truncated elements
$(document).on('click','.truncated', toggleTruncate);
```

```css
.truncated {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show-truncated {
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.show-fulltext {
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.truncated:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      Header
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid;">
        <span class="truncated show-truncated" data-truncated="Truncated Text..." data-fulltext="This is the full text content">
          Truncated Text...
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```